# When NestedScrollView nested RecyclerView,ViewHolder will not recycle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I set the setRecyclerListener to see if there is a recycle;
When there is no NestedScrollView, ViewHolder will be reclaimed and print log;
When nested in NestedScrollView, view will not be recycled and will not print log, when the item more and more, resulting in memory soaring.

```
recyclerView.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerView.RecyclerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        Log.d("onViewRecycled", "recycled------->" + holder);
    }
});
```

Comment: try this make your Recyclerview **`mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`**

Comment: that's the expected behavior (atm). I reported it as bug to Google in December last year. The only workaround is to nest a RV in a RV

Comment: I have setNestedScrollingEnabled false, but it still does not reclaim ViewHolder.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I faced this question as you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `android:fillViewport="true"` property to `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Specify:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

in your Java file.